# Rails: How do I loop through an undefined number of possible parents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following scenario set up: a model (Group) which can have many parents of the same type, and hence many children. All is working well - a group can belong to many groups, and have many groups as children. My models are defined as follows:

**group.rb**

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :parent_child_relationships, :class_name => "GroupRelationship", :foreign_key => :child_id, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :parents, :through => :parent_child_relationships, :source => :parent

  has_many :child_parent_relationships, :class_name => "GroupRelationship", :foreign_key => :parent_id, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :children, :through => :child_parent_relationships, :source => :child

end
```

**group_relationship.rb**

```
class GroupRelationship < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Group"
  belongs_to :child, :class_name => "Group"

end
```

I want to allow users (User) to join groups. I plan to have a simple setup with Users having many Groups through UserGroups and Groups having many Users through UserGroups.

However, when a User joins a Group, I would like to run a method that ensures that the User also joins all parents of that Group. Now, the possible number of parents is unknown. Normally I would do something like:

**user_group.rb**

```
class UserGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  after_create :join_parent_groups

  def join_parent_groups
    if self.group.parents.size > 0
      self.group.parents.each do |parent|
        UserGroup.create!(:group_id => parent.id, :user_id => self.user_id)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Any thoughts on how I could recursively loop through the parents of the parents, and the parents of the parents of that parent etc? As a terrible solution I could do this loop a set number of times (like 10, for example) which would work for most cases - but it's not foolproof.

Thanks!

Comment: You should look into the [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) or [closure tree gem](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree)

Comment: Thanks - initially I considered Ancestry but it seemed overkill for a relatively simple scenario, which I have working fine (except for the above method). May have to look again at Ancestry since I can certainly see the value of a 'descendents/ancestors' method.

Comment: Ancestry will help, but I agree - it does seem overkill. You just need a recursive function.

Comment: Does your code not work as it stands? - the `UserGroup.create!` should trigger the `after_create` callback which would bubble up the parent groups??

Comment: btw, you can remove the `if self.group.parents.size > 0` conditional as the each will not do anything without any elements and `self.group.parents` will always return an array.

Comment: I would support @Andi, `join_parent_groups` should work as it is. But I would consider something like _only if the user is not yet part of the group_.

Comment: thanks guys - Andy, I hadn't even considered that ... I think it will work as you say. I'll give it a try, I just hadn't got round to setting up the models yet.